# Class template argument deduction - why does it fail here?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, template-argument-deduction, ctad

Why does the following CTAD attempt fail to compile ?

```
template <typename T> struct C { C(T,T) {} };
template <> struct C<int> { C(int) {} };

C c(1);  //error: template argument deduction failure
```

I would have expected that the constructor C(int) would have been deduced.

Comment: CTAD only respects the constructors of the primary template.

Answer (score 7):

Implicit deduction guides are only generated for constructors in the primary template, not for constructors of specializations.

You need to add the deduction guide explicitly:

```
C(int) -> C<int>;
```